# Laravel-Undefined variable in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem while I was trying to use the $user variable, I'm pretty new to laravel but from what I can gather my controller file isn't able to pass the variable $user to my blade file. I have tried many solutions but I'm still not able to solve this problem. These are the files that I use:

Blade file:

```
<body>
 <div class="justify-center flex text-center shadow-sm max-w-xs m-auto">
  <img src="{{$user->image}}" id="imageName" class="object-cover w-24 h-24 float-left mr-5">
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <form action="{{ route ('update_profile', $user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
 <input type="file" name="picture" id="my-file">
<input type="submit" name="Upload">
</form>
<br>
    <div class="space-x-8 flex justify-between mt-32 md:mt-0 md:justify-center text-center">
<button class="text-black py-2 px-4 uppercase rounded bg-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 shadow hover:shadow-lg font-medium transition transform hover:-translate-y-0.5">
  Connect
</button>
    <button class="text-black py-2 px-4 uppercase rounded bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-800 shadow hover:shadow-lg font-medium transition transform hover:-translate-y-0.5">
  Message
</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="mt-20 text-center border-b pb-12">
    <h1 class="text-4xl font-medium text-gray-700">Jessica Jones</h1>
    <p class="font-light text-gray-600 mt-3">123 Address</p>

    <p class="mt-8 text-gray-500">Rentee</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mt-12 flex flex-col justify-center">
    <p class="text-gray-600 text-center font-light lg:px-16">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <div class="justify-center flex text-center">
    <button class="text-indigo-500 py-2 px-4  font-medium mt-4 ">
  Show more
</button>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
  document.getElementById("my-file").onchange = function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // e.target.result is a base64-encoded url that contains the image data
      document.getElementById('imageName').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>

</html>

<?php
```

Controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

  public function update_profile(Request $request,$id) {
    $rquest->validate([
      'picture'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
    unlink($user->image);


    $image_name = $request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('public/images/profile/'),$image_name);
    $path = 'images/profile/'.$image_name;
    $user->image = $path;
    $user->save();
    return view('profile', compact ('user'));
 }
}
```

Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'size',
    ];
}
```

This is the error that I encountered

[image]

I have tried adding compact('user') to the return view line in the controller, tried using ['user' => $user] at the same return line and also clearing the route cache but they all resulted in the same error.

Comment: "This is the error that I encountered" - please share all error messages **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `dd($user);` before your return to see what's in the user variable.

Comment: fyi, typo in `$rquest->validate(...)`

Comment: The HTML source in your error message does not match the HTML you posted in your question, are you certain this is the correct file?

Comment: perhaps there is another route action that is returning this view as well (which is not having the correct data passed to it)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the user Instead of Update. Please update the user.

```
$user = User::where("id",$id)->firstOrFail();
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
$user->user_role = $request->user_role;
$user->updated_at = Carbon::now();
$updateUser = $user->update();
return view('profile',compact("user"));
```

**More important**

- Please share all error messages in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem.
- Before your return the user, please see what's in the user variable.( dd($user); ).
- The HTML source in your error message does not match the HTML you posted in your
  question.
- Please use validate method properly.

Answer (score -1):

try to use instead `compact($user)` send data to blade using `with('user', $user)`

```
return view('profile')->with('user', $user);
```

**update**

how you ar doing update from your user and you use method save() you can´t return result.

if you do this:

```
$user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

    return $this->success('profile','Profile updated successfully!');
```

you can return message or result. Also you can use this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
            $user->name = $request->get('name');
            $user->email = $request->get('email');
            $user->password = \Hash::make($request->get('password'));
            
            $user->update();  

            if($user){
                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'User updated!');
            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', ' Error!');
            }
```

Comment: thanks I tried it but it still results in the same error

Comment: and `return view('profile', ['user' => $user]);` ?

Comment: @zacksnyder3 in your controller if you do var_dump() or print_r() what contains?

Comment: still get the same error @geertjanknapen

Comment: @scorpions78 how do i do var_dump() or print_r() in my controller?

Comment: @zacksnyder3 ok. Your problem it´s that you have return user and this variable it´s result to update. If you want return result update. update my answer

Comment: @zacksnyder3 in your controller you can to do print_r() or var_dump() in this line for example; print_r($user->save()); or var_dump($user->save()) but if use save() you can´t return nothing

Comment: You can use Laravel's `dd()` or `dump()` helpers instead (`dd()` dumps and dies, `dump()` just dumps)